# YAML Extend Stage Template

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

Looking to try and get some help figuring out a solution to what seems like a simple task. I am trying to develop some extend YAML templates for security within our ADO pipelines but first I have to get passed this error I am experiencing.

The error being returned by ADO when I try to validate or run the pipeline is
`/ADO_Stage_Restrictions_Dev.yml@AdoRestrictions (Line: 7, Col: 3): Unexpected value job`

**Working Extend Template YAML**

*This template validates and executes without issue, which to me means I am successfully passing the stages object into the extends template*

```
parameters:
  - name: stageObjs
    type: stageList
    default: []

stages:
- ${{ each stage in parameters.stageObjs }}:
    ${{ stage }}
```

**Broken Extend Template YAML**

*This template does not validate and throws the 'Unexpected value job' exception. based on the stage schema I would assume that I would be able to loop the jobs property within the stage.*

```
parameters:
  - name: stageObjs
    type: stageList
    default: []

stages:
- ${{ each stage in parameters.stageObjs }}:
  - ${{ each job in stage.jobs }}:
      ${{ job }}
```

**Build YAML**

*The main yaml file that extends stages*

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: self
      type: git
      ref: refs/heads/Development
      
    - repository: AdoRestrictions
      type: git
      name: utl-yaml-templates
      ref: refs/heads/main

trigger: none

pool:
    name: PROD    

extends:
  template: ADO_Stage_Restrictions_Dev.yml@AdoRestrictions
  parameters:
    stageObjs:
      - stage: 'BuildStage'
        displayName: 'Build Test'
        jobs:
          - job: 'BuildJob'
            displayName: 'Build'
            steps:
            - task: PowerShell@2
              displayName: 'Hello World'
              inputs:
                targetType: inline
                script: |
                  Write-Host "Hello World"
```

Comment: Hi Bri, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Can I ask a question? What is it that you're trying to do with the 'broken' extend template yaml, that you can't do with the working version?

Comment: Vince, thank you for the warm welcome. I am trying to access the jobsList object of each stage. The samples I provide are not detailing the intent of what I am trying to accomplish, as I wanted to keep my question as simple as possible.  Once I am able to access the jobList object I will work down into the tasks and disable the use of scripting tasks and some other security concerns my organization has.  I have already created a POC that works if I send a jobList object to the extends template, but I need to be able to access that same jobList object in the stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in your yaml which defines the start of the stage, or declares the start of the list of jobs; that's why it wasn't expecting to find 'job' there. You can add those parts in, like this:

```
parameters:
  - name: stageObjs
    type: stageList
    default: []

stages:
- ${{ each stage in parameters.stageObjs }}:
  - stage: ${{ stage.stage }}
    displayName: ${{ stage.displayName }}
    jobs: 
      - ${{ each job in stage.jobs }}:
          ${{ job }}
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the new question I posted and let me know what your thoughts are. [New Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72605141/yaml-extends-template-unrecognized-value-else-located-at-position-1-within)