# YAML Extends Template - Unrecognized value: 'else'. Located at position 1 within expression: else

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, devops, extends, azure-pipelines-yaml

Expanding on my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72532194/yaml-extend-stage-template/72564221#72564221). I am now experiencing a new error `Unrecognized value: 'else'. Located at position 1 within expression: else` that I cannot figure out a solution to. The issue happens when I add the 'else' condition within the foreach of the job.steps.

**Build YAML**

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: self
      type: git
      ref: refs/heads/Development
      
    - repository: AdoRestrictions
      type: git
      name: utl-yaml-templates
      ref: refs/heads/main

trigger: none

pool:
    name: PROD    

extends:
  template: ADO_Stage_Restrictions_Dev.yml@AdoRestrictions
  parameters:
    stageObjs:
      - stage: 'BuildStage'
        displayName: 'Build Test'
        jobs:
          - job: 'BuildJob'
            displayName: 'Build'
            steps:
            - task: PowerShell@2
              displayName: 'PS Hello World'
              inputs:
                targetType: inline
                script: |
                  Write-Host "Hello World"
```

**Working Extends YAML**

```
parameters:
  - name: stageObjs
    type: stageList
    default: []

stages:
- ${{ each stage in parameters.stageObjs }}:
  - stage: ${{ stage.stage }}
    displayName: ${{ stage.displayName }}
    jobs: 
    - ${{ each job in stage.jobs }}:          
      - job: ${{ job.job }}
        displayName: ${{ job.displayName }}
        steps:          
        - ${{ each step in job.steps }}:
          - ${{ if or(startsWith(step.task, 'PowerShell'),startsWith(step.task, 'CmdLine'),startsWith(step.task, 'Bash'),startsWith(step.task, 'ShellScript'),containsValue(step.task, 'Script'),containsValue(step.task, 'CLI'),containsValue(step.task, 'PowerShell')) }}:         
            - task: PowerShell@2
              displayName: 'Unapproved - ${{ step.displayName }}'
              inputs:
                targetType: inline                        
                script: Write-Output "Unapproved Task - Scripting and CLI tasks are not approved for use in yaml pipelines"
```

**Broken Extends YAML**

```
parameters:
  - name: stageObjs
    type: stageList
    default: []

stages:
- ${{ each stage in parameters.stageObjs }}:
  - stage: ${{ stage.stage }}
    displayName: ${{ stage.displayName }}
    jobs: 
    - ${{ each job in stage.jobs }}:          
      - job: ${{ job.job }}
        displayName: ${{ job.displayName }}
        steps:          
        - ${{ each step in job.steps }}:
          - ${{ if or(startsWith(step.task, 'PowerShell'),startsWith(step.task, 'CmdLine'),startsWith(step.task, 'Bash'),startsWith(step.task, 'ShellScript'),containsValue(step.task, 'Script'),containsValue(step.task, 'CLI'),containsValue(step.task, 'PowerShell')) }}:         
            - task: PowerShell@2
              displayName: 'Unapproved - ${{ step.displayName }}'
              inputs:
                targetType: inline                        
                script: Write-Output "Unapproved Task - Scripting and CLI tasks are not approved for use in yaml pipelines"                  
          - ${{ else }}:
            - ${{ step }}
```

**Full Error Message**

```
(Line: 22, Col: 13): Unrecognized value: 'else'. Located at position 1 within expression: else. (Line: 22, Col: 13): Expected at least one key-value pair in the mapping
```

**Update - Working Solution**

```
parameters:
  - name: stageObjs
    type: stageList
    default: []

stages:
- ${{ each stage in parameters.stageObjs }}:
  - stage: ${{ stage.stage }}
    displayName: ${{ stage.displayName }}
    jobs: 
    - ${{ each job in stage.jobs }}:          
      - job: ${{ job.job }}
        displayName: ${{ job.displayName }}
        steps:          
        - ${{ each step in job.steps }}:

            #Disallow any type of scripting tasks
            - ${{ if or(startsWith(step.task, 'PowerShell'),startsWith(step.task, 'CmdLine'),startsWith(step.task, 'Bash'),startsWith(step.task, 'ShellScript'),contains(step.task, 'Script'),contains(step.task, 'CLI'),contains(step.task, 'PowerShell')) }}:                   
              - task: PowerShell@2
                displayName: 'Unapproved Task - ${{ step.displayName }}'
                inputs:
                  targetType: inline                        
                  script: throw "Unapproved Task - Scripting and CLI tasks are not approved for use in yaml pipelines" 

            #Not a scripting task perform additional checks
            - ${{ if and(not(startsWith(step.task, 'PowerShell')),not(startsWith(step.task, 'CmdLine')),not(startsWith(step.task, 'Bash')),not(startsWith(step.task, 'ShellScript')),not(contains(step.task, 'Script')),not(contains(step.task, 'CLI')),not(contains(step.task, 'PowerShell')) ) }}:         
              
              #Validate azure subscription provided for the environment 
              - ${{ if contains(step.task, 'Azure') }}:                                                      
                - ${{ each pair in step }}:                                                       
                    ${{ if eq(pair.key, 'inputs') }}:
                      inputs:
                        ${{ each attribute in pair.value }}:
                          ${{ if contains(attribute.key, 'Subscription') }}:
                            ${{ if and(ne(attribute.value, 'sub-name1'), ne(attribute.value, 'sub-name2'), ne(attribute.value, 'sub-name3')) }}:
                              ${{ attribute.value }}: ''
                            ${{ if or(eq(attribute.value, 'sub-name1'), eq(attribute.value, 'sub-name2'), eq(attribute.value, 'sub-anme3')) }}:
                              ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}
                    ${{ if ne(pair.key, 'inputs') }}:
                      ${{ if eq(pair.key, 'displayName') }}:
                        ${{ pair.key }}: 'Invalid Azure Subscription - ${{ pair.value }}'
                      ${{ if ne(pair.key, 'displayName') }}:
                        ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}

              #Allow all other tasks  
              - ${{ if not(contains(step.task, 'Azure')) }}:
                - ${{ step }}
```

Comment: Hi Bri; can I check, are you using any kind of syntax and formatting checker, such as the official Visual Studio Code extension, [Azure Pipelines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azure-devops.azure-pipelines) from microsoft?

Comment: I am using both, but mainly Azure Pipeline validation.  I did figure out a solution (work around) to my issue.  I reversed the conditions

- ${{ if contains(step.task, 'PowerShell') }}:        
   - [[ do work here for powershell tasks]]
- ${{ if not(contains(step.task, 'PowerShell')) }}:
   - [[ do work here for non powershell tasks]]

Comment: See the update that I added to my post.

Comment: If you found a working solution, you can add it as an answer and not edit it into your post.  It will be more obvious to others who might find this question later.